# Can I use websocket in client and socket.io in server?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

As in the question,

since socket.io is a wrapper around websocket and uses it when it can, I think I can mix websocket (on the client) and socket.io (on the server), can I?

Or it could be the other way around, socket.io on the client and websocket on the server, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Websockets are one transport that `socket.io` can use, but it implements its own protocol on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io has client libraries for a variety of clients, you might want to use that.

You probably know that though and I'm going to assume there is a reason for you to avoid socket.io's client libraries and want to use a different websocket implementation. I'm 99% sure you can. I seem to be unable to find an example that makes it work (you probably couldn't as well).